# How to preprocess strings in Keras models Lambda layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have the problem that the value passed on to the Lambda layer (at compile time) is a placeholder generated by keras (without values). When the model is compiled, the .eval () method throws the error:

> You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype
>   string and shape [?, 1]

```py
def text_preprocess(x):
  strings = tf.keras.backend.eval(x)
  vectors = []
  for string in strings:
    vector = string_to_one_hot(string.decode('utf-8'))
    vectors.append(vector)
  vectorTensor = tf.constant(np.array(vectors),dtype=tf.float32)
  return vectorTensor

input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = Lambda(text_preprocess)(input_text)
dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(embedding)
outputs = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(dense)

model = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.save('test.h5')
```

If I pass a string array into the input layer statically, I can compile the model, but I get the same error if I want to convert the model to tflite.

```py
#I replaced this line:
input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)

#by this lines:
test = tf.constant(["Hello","World"])
input_text = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string, tensor=test)

#but calling this ...
converter = TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('string_test.h5')
tfmodel = converter.convert()

#... still leads to this error:
```

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'input_3' with dtype string and shape [2]      [[{{node input_3}}]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally solved it that way:

```py
def text_preprocess(x):
  b = tf.strings.unicode_decode(x,'UTF-8')
  b = b.to_tensor(default_value=0)
  #do things with decoded string
  one_hot = K.one_hot(b,one_hot_size)
  return one_hot

...
```